Why only one structure argument can be passed by value through Callback interface, the rest arguments are ignored?
public class SampleStruct extends Structure {
    public static class ByReference extends SampleStruct implements Structure.ByReference {}

    public static class ByValue extends SampleStruct implements Structure.ByValue {}

    public int x;
    public int y;
}

class SampleMethod implements Callback {

    public void invoke(SampleStruct.ByValue s, int z) {
        // The "z" argument will always be ignored (0) when called from native code.
    }
}

Why the "z" argument of the invoke method above was always 0 when called from the native code? The "s" argument is correct.
class SampleMethod implements Callback {

    public void invoke(int z, SampleStruct.ByValue s) {
        // The "z" argument is passed correct
    }
}

The "z" argument is correct when I tried to change the argument position.

What is the native code signature you're representing?   It's rare that structures are passed by value.  Are you keeping a reference to the structure after sending it to the callback?  It's backed by native memory and can be garbage collected.
